# Why does "AT cut" of Quartz provide pure shear thickness oscillation?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, crystals, resonance, piezoelectric

According to this page https://www.nanoscience.com/techniques/quartz-crystal-microbalance/,

> “AT cut”  provides pure thickness shear mode oscillation where the two surfaces of the crystal move in an anti-parallel fashion.

How can I model and derive this result mathematically? 
I guess I would have to make and solve wave equations considering piezoelectric effect in quartz crystal, but I am lost where I should start.
Any reference or help are appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It has to do with crystal orientation, crystal symmetry, and the elastic constants tensor.

Answer (score 2):

Although I have not derived any of these equations, I can safely say that you will find a beginning of an answer in a book by Royer and Dieulesaint, *Elastic waves in Solids* volume 1, section 4. I'm pretty sure to find a definite answer, you'll have to solve the specific Christoffel equation. 
I think it has to do indeed, as pointed out by Jon Custer, to the crystal orientation and symmetry. (As defined by standards IEEE 176-1978) the AT cut has angles $\theta = 35$ deg and $\varphi = 0$. 
The angles are defined as:

1. $\varphi$ is the first rotation aroud axis Z in the crystalline structure, giving axes $X^\prime$, $Y^\prime$ and $Z^\prime=Z$.
2. $\theta$ is the angle of the second rotation aroud axis $X^\prime$

Another reference you might want to check is *An analysis of doubly rotated quartz resonators utilizing essentially thickness modes with transverse variation* by Stevens and Tiersten, you may find useful information there.
Hope you find any useful information in these references

Answer (score 0):

"The Quartz Crystal Microbalance in Soft Matter Research: Fundamentals and Modeling" by Diethelm Johannsmann has a chapter dedicated to modeling QCM as a parallel plate.  If you are interested in the application aspects of QCM, I highly recommend this book.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/419260)